# INotifyPropertyChanged usages out of WPF/Silverlight world

Tags: .net, user-interface, clr, inotifypropertychanged

Can anybody give me any examples of `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` (and maybe `INotifyPropertyChanging`) interfaces usage in some popular .NET libraries or maybe UI frameworks, custom controls kits, etc, but out of WPF/Silverlight world?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Forms uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` for data binding and did so well before WPF/Silverlight. The only thing that actually uses `INotifyPropertyChanging` is LINQ To SQL, and there it is used for change tracking in entity classes.